# creating construct method in model in joomla3

Tags: joomla3.0

I have two methods in model in joomla 3 that uses the same database connection.How can I do it.I opt to do it creating the databse connection in costruct method in model.But didnt work.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

e.g
if you have two methods `method1()` & `method2()` you can create third method `db_connection()`. in method1 & method2 you can call like this

```
$con=$this->db_connection();
```

---

btw in joomla we get database connection by

```
$con=JFactory::getDbo();
```